# Cancel on popup edit dialog resets data

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have this example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/IhEdu

There is column CanDelete in data to hide/show "delete" command column. Column is removed in dataBound based on CanDelete value.

Now try to click on "edit" text in grid then "cancel" in popup dialog. And "delete" appears right of "edit". But this column has been deleted on dataBound.

It has something to do with schema, because removing schema fixed this. Why? What's wrong with this schema definition?

Thnx for help

Answer (score 0):

I think the row gets rebuilt when the dialog closes.

Try replacing the commands and the dataBound handler with a CanDelete template

```
{ 
  field: "CanDelete", 
  template: "<a class='k-grid-edit'> edit </a> #if(CanDelete){#<a class='k-grid-delete'> delete </a>#}#" 
}
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/IhEdu/10

Comment: Well, it should be a workaround, but why it works fine if there is no scheme defined?

Comment: @Raptor It looks to me like dataBound gets called after cancelling the dialog only if there is no schema. However, the update doesn't seems to work without the schema.